# what are the possible reasons for web page to be misaligned in different systems?

Tags: web-applications, resolution

I created a web application that looks perfectly fine in the browser of my system.

But when it is viewed in a different system, same version browser the web page is misaligned. One possible reason for this might be this system has a different resolution.

Are there any other reasons for this to happen ?

How can we develop a web page that works fine on all resolutions ?

Note :I am not talking about different browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a different screen resolution would have that effect (I've had that happen to me a couple of times).